# What is exactly server.error.path property?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, properties-file

In Spring Boot, what is the purpose of `server.error.path` property in application.properties file?

The documentation just says:

> Path of the error controller

But I want a clear description of this property with an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`server.error.path` - used as part of url for error pages.

```
site.getBaseUrl() + "/error"
```

For example some error happen on server side and you decide redirect user to error page like this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/images/custom-error-page-aws-404-example.png

Code example of error controller you can find here:

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/implementing-error-controller.html

You can use this property in `@RequestMapping("/error")`. But instead of `"/error"` you can use `"${server.error.path}"`

**UPDATE:**

Also, Spring Boot `BasicErrorController` use `server.error.path` property

Answer (score 3):

Property `server.error.path` in spring boot application used to define an error path while dealing with custom error handler. In Spring we create custom error handler using functional interface `ErrorController`, ths interface has a String type method `getErrorPath` which helps us to return the error page path(our error page as view).
But from Spring 2.3.0 this `getErrorPath()` method has been deprecated and replaced with `server.error.path` to manage the error path.

e.g. `server.error.path=/error`

For more detail about interface **ErrorController**, please refer Spring doc for [ErrorController](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/error/ErrorController.html)